# Offsetting multiple icons on the same point

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Have a map that shows reviews of parks.  Some members have multiple reviews at one park, so there are 2 or more icons stacked on top of one another.

Is there a method in Google Maps v3 to offset icons that are on the same physical location by a very small distance?  This way when the mapped is zoomed, readers can see multiple review icons and read each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Marker Spiderfier](http://googlemapsmania.blogspot.com/2012/05/mappiness-marker-spiderfier-library.html) is one option (but it isn't part of the Google Maps API v3, it is a third party extension).